# Eclipse上で作成したサーブレットをTomcat上で実行

Tags: java, tomcat

Eclipse上で作成したサーブレットを実際の別のマシンのTOMCATで動作させるための設定がわかりません

開発環境は
Windows7/64
Eclipse4.4(32ビット)
Eclipseに内蔵されたTomcat8(32ビット)
JRE1.8(32ビット)
で、
動作環境は
Windows2008R2
Tomcat8(32ビット)
JRE1.8(32ビット)
です
JRE等が32ビットなのはJNAから32ビットで作成されたDLLをコールするためです

Eclipse上では
パッケージ名 TPack
サーブレット名 TServ
として作成しました

Tomcatでは
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps
配下に
webtestフォルダを作成し
webtest
→WEB-INF
    -→classes
      eclipseのプロジェクトのbuildフォルダ配下のclassファイルを全てコピー
    -→lib
　　　jna.jar
     win32-x86.jar
というフォルダ構成にし、
WEB-INFフォルダ直下の
web.xmlファイルに

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TServ</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webtest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

としてみたのですが、
The requested resource is not available.
としかサーバが返してきません
サーブレットの名前やurlを大文字小文字を組み合わせを変えてみたりしたのですが、やはり変わりませんでした

正しいweb.xml等の記述方法を教えてください
また、現在はアプリのwebappsフォルダに配置しているのですが
出来れば、別のフォルダにアプリを構築したいので、その記述方法も教えていただきたいです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseのTomcatでは、アプリケーション実行に問題ないことが前提ですが、

プロジェクトエクスプローラーにて、対象のプロジェクトの上で右クリックをし、

エクスポート　＞　WARエクスポート

でwar形式でエクスポートします。

それを動作させたいTomcatのwebappsにコピーしてから、Tomcatを起動してください。
自動的にwarファイルが展開され、アプリケーションとして搭載（デプロイ）されますのでお試しください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
無事作成したページが動作しました
こんな方法があるなんて全然知りませんでした・・・